# unable to send PUT request changing only imageUri and employeeBio

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, state

I fetched this data from the WebAPI and would like to update the value of imageUri and employeeBio in the Web Api. I am only able to edit the Bio for now, and  now i would like to send PUT request to update the value of imageUri and employeeBio, but unable to do so. My onPress method of Save button seems to be not working as well, as I am unable to get the alert when the press the button. Thank you!

This is the JSON data that is present in the url.

```
[
  {
    "imageUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/React-icon.svg/1200px-React-icon.svg.png", 
    "departmentName": "Test Department", 
    "employeeName": "Test Employee", 
    "employeeBio": "Test Bio"
  }
]
```

This is the PUT method for the profile Data in **DataLoad.js**. Since users are only able to change Image and io, we only accept values of imageUrl and employeeBio when calling PUT request.

```js
export function updateProfileData(params) {
  return fetch('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cgdMFRuLTm?indent=2', {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({params}),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      if (result === 'ok') {
        alert('Profile Updated Successfully!');
        this.setState({
          imageUrl: this.state.items[0].imageUrl,
          employeeBio: this.state.items[0].employeeBio
        })
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert('Profile Update Failed!')
      console.log(`error = ${error}`);
    });
}
```

Since I am still fairly new to React-Native, I had to scramble through multiple videos and guides to make the GET request work. This is what I currently have in my Profile.js file where I will call the GET request and PUT request.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      employeeName: '',
      departmentName: '',
      employeeBio: '',
      imageUrl: ''
    };
    this.getProfileData = getProfileData.bind(this);
    this.updateProfileData = updateProfileData.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProfileData();
  }



  render() {
    var { isLoaded } = this.state
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.piccontainer}>
            <Image
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}
              source={{ uri: this.state.items[0].imageUrl }}
              style={styles.photo} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.textcontainer}>
            <View style={styles.listView}>
              <Text style={styles.label}>Name </Text>
              <Text style={styles.name}>{this.state.items[0].employeeName}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.listView}>
              <Text style={styles.label}>Department </Text>
              <Text style={styles.name}>{this.state.items[0].departmentName}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.listView}>
              <Text style={styles.label}>Bio </Text>
              <TextInput
                multiline={true}
                numberOfLines={4}
                style={styles.input}
                value={this.state.items[0].employeeBio}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({
                  items: this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
                    i == 0 ?
                      { ...item, employeeBio: text } : item)
                })
                } />
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.text}
                  onPress={() => {
                    let params = {
                      imageUrl: this.state.items[0].imageUrl,
                      employeeBio: this.state.items[0].employeeBio
                    };
                    updateProfileData(params);
                  }
                  } >
                  Save
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
```

Edited: I am now able to change the value, but i am still facing issues calling the PUT request and updating the value on the Web API. It seems like my onPress method in the **Save** button is not working properly as im not getting the alert showing that i have Updated Profile Successfully. Thank you for the help again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the method you provided `updateProfileData` is not receiving any params in its definition.

Secondly the way you are using spread operator in `onChange` event is not the right way to change state variable which is an array. You can do this in object but not in array. You need to update the correct object in array for that you should use some looping mechanism to get to the object to be updated so you should do something like this: `this.setState({items: this.state.items.map((item, i) => i==0 ? {...item, bio: text} : item)});`
Here i==0 works for your case. You can use example dynamically too.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey! The onChange worked, but im not able to call the onPress function of the Save button. I've also edited the last part of the question where I have stated that the onPress is not working properly. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You don’t have to use `then` clause when you are calling upadteProfile method. In your updateProfile method, handle the request response and use `setState` accordingly. You can use alerts in your update function definition.

Comment: Also `then` clause works when you return promise from a function. If you want to do that, then only return first `then` clause i.e response.json(). Then you can write like this updateProfileData(params).then(jsonResp => <your functionality>)

Comment: So I'm handling request response and setState at the UpdateProfile method as you have told, still no luck. I've also updated the codes to show what I've done. Is this problem due to trying to update only 2 of the 4 values there? I don;t think that is a problem as my PUT WebAPI is designed to only accept 2 values, imageUrl and employeeBio

Comment: What does your PUT call returns as a response? You should put debugger before your condition result === “ok” to know what actually is coming in result.

Comment: ahh, so in the onPress method, i  have to do ```this.updateProfile(params)```?

Comment: Yes, as you have to use this.setState in your method and also for that you’ve bound your method with `this`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206187/discussion-between-min-ud-and-muhammad-hassan-khan).

Comment: Put your onPress event call on TouchableOpacity component instead of Text component.

Comment: Hey! what if we were to be working with huge amount of data, instead of ```i=0``` how should i set it so that it works dynamically?

Comment: Then your condition should tell which record to update, like let’s assume if you have ids in every item object and you want to update specific item with let’s say ID=1 then your condition will become item.id == Id. Here Id will be passed from any event and you’ll be receiving that in function param maybe.